# Getting Error Object { headers: {…}, status: 0... } when making a POST request from Angular to Spring boot server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, cors

I am trying to solve this issue when I make a POST request from my Angular App (on localhost:4200) I get this error with status 0:

> Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8081/chordproject/api/changeScale/A", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8081/chordproject/api/changeScale/A: 0 Unknown Error", error: abort }

My controller in my spring-boot app has a GET method and it works properly.  I know this problem is related to CORS and I also applied some filtering in my controller. If I make the POST request from Postman I successfully get the correct response.

My Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    ChordServiceInterface chordServiceInterface;
    
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping("/getAllChordsInScale/{scale}/{modality}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Chord>> getAllChordsInScale(@PathVariable String scale, @PathVariable String modality) { 
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Chord>>(chordServiceInterface.getAllChordsInScale(scale, modality), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @PostMapping("/changeScale/{scale}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Chord>> changeScale(@RequestBody List<Chord> chordList, @PathVariable String scale) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Chord>>(chordServiceInterface.getTrasposeChords(chordList, scale), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
}
```

My Angular Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChordService {

  url: string = "http://localhost:8081/chordproject/api/";

  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAllChordsInScale(scale : String, modality: String): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + "getAllChordsInScale/" + scale + "/" + modality, { headers: this.headers });
  } 

  getTrasposedChords(scale: String, chordList: Chord[]): Observable<any> {
    const body = JSON.stringify(chordList);
    console.log(this.url + "changeScale/" + scale);
    return  this.httpClient.post(this.url + "changeScale/" + scale, body, { headers: this.headers });
  }

}
```

I also added in my angular app a proxy configuration in my package.json folder:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8081",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And declared it in my package.json in the start section

```
"start": "ng serve — proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

Comment: You can create a proxy in Angular for you API. Look at "Proxying to a backend server" in
 https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: If you are sure, the POST request works from Postman with the same headers, ..., then it must be an Angular issue, I guess. HTTP status `0` does not exist - so maybe the request was never send?
Btw you shouldn't send the content-type with your GET request without JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your angular proxy is proxying your requests. You are proxying requests to "/api" but you are requesting "/api/{something}".

You should try a better pattern, as:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8081/chordproject",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And for the angular code, the url server target will be set by the proxy and then I don't think that you need the Access Control Allow Origin Header.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChordService {

  url: string = "/api/";

  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAllChordsInScale(scale : String, modality: String): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + "getAllChordsInScale/" + scale + "/" + modality, { headers: this.headers });
  } 

  getTrasposedChords(scale: String, chordList: Chord[]): Observable<any> {
    const body = JSON.stringify(chordList);
    console.log(this.url + "changeScale/" + scale);
    return  this.httpClient.post(this.url + "changeScale/" + scale, body, { headers: this.headers });
  }

}
```

Also, be wary with your api path names as they are not the best. (get in the name when you already do a http get, not applying on an objet, not really rest)

Comment: Correct, my configuration wasn't proxying my http request.  I have fixed it now but I am getting the same error as before only difference is that the url is now `(http://localhost:4200/chordproject/api/changeScale/B)`

Comment: that makes no sense, it should be `http://localhost:4200/api/changeScale/B` or `http://localhost:8081/chordproject/api/changeScale/A`. Have you updated your service too?

Comment: Yes I have, I added chordproject just because I can easily remove the proxy and it should still make the correct calls to my server.
Service: `url: string = "chordproject/api/";`
proxy.json `"/chordproject/api/*": {`

Comment: If you're using "/chordproject/api" in your service, you're supposed to use "/chordproject/api/*" in the proxy. Is the get even working? Get is easier to configure

Comment: Yes, the Get method is working.

Comment: Good. So take a look at your body, you're not supposed to need to stringify it, as angular does it for you. What's inside your Chord class? Also, maybe the content-type is wrong and may need to be "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: My Chord class is a simple DTO with 6 different attributes and the constructor.